# PHP 5.4.16 and FreeTDS (php_dblib.dll): Unable to load extension

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, apache, freetds

**Goal**

Connect to a ***MSSQL 2008 R2*** server using the ***[FreeTDS (php_dblib.dll 0.82 + 20110906 patches)](http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP)*** Drivers for ***PHP 5.4.16 (VC9)***.

*I am unable to use any alternative to FreeTDS unless the client also decides to use an alternative. This is unlikely unless they also run into this issue when upgrading their current version of PHP (currently 5.3.x) tomorrow.*

**Issue**

PHP is unable to load the FreeTDS extension.

The Apache error log displays this on server start:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.16/ext/php_dblib.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

As far as I understand it, the extension is either unable to be found or is the wrong version?

The extension directory location in the php.ini has been checked and triple checked and is:

```
c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.16/ext/
```

That leads me to believe it is the wrong version of php_dblib.dll. I've also checked that multiple times and made sure to use the version for PHP 5.4.X Thread Safe.

**Steps Taken**

- Clean install of WAMP 2.4 with PHP 5.4.16 and Apache 2.4.4
- Thread Safe php_dblib.dll placed in PHP extension directory
- `extension=php_dblib.dll` added to the correct php.ini
- `extension=php_mssql.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll` disabled in php.ini
- msvcr71.dll (DotNet framework 1.1) added to PHP root directory
- freetds.conf added to server root directory (c:)

**System Details**

- WAMP Server 2.4
- Apache 2.4.4
- PHP 5.4.16 (VC9)

  - Thread Safety: enabled
- FreeTDS Thread Safe (php_dblib.dll) 0.82 + 20110906 patches
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
- msvcr71.dll (DotNet framework 1.1) *only included in the PHP root directory*

***EDIT:***

- WAMP 2.4 32-bit
- OS: Windows 7 Pro 64-bit

***EDIT 3***

Last update only applied to the 64-bit version of WAMP. I've installed the 32-bit version, again, and `--without-dblib` is no longer in the configure command section of the phpinfo().

**Questions**

- With the information given, is there anything else you'd need to know about to give an accurate assessment of the situation?
- I am unable to find any, but are there any known issues with FreeTDS 0.82 and PHP 5.4.16?

**Temporary Defeat**

I've rolled back to PHP 5.3.x for now, FreeTDS works fine on that version. I'm not sure that it will make a difference with the little bit of code I am actually delivering to the client. This was intended to be a "double" check to make sure it all works perfectly, but since I'll be on site during the install I can fix any issues if they come up.

I would like to find a solution eventually since more and more of the systems I work with every day are going to be upgraded to php 5.4 and beyond.

Comment: I am on the same page as you cant figure this one out... did you manage at all to get this working?

Comment: @Chopnut We ended up taking a different route with the project and I don't believe anything ever came of this. Good luck finding a solution!

Comment: @Eric All in all, I just decided to use whatever library is currently available. Instead of mimicking our production server on my windows machine. Thats all I could ever do.